# Dynamic execution of a DLT pipeline for SCD2 creation in Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-synapse, delta-live-tables

I am trying to load my datalake SCD2 tables via Databricks DLT pipeline. My goal is to dynamically load the tables in a notebook by passing the required information in the "Configuration" setting in the DLT pipeline.

The "Configuration" setting could look like this:

```
{
    "object1": {
        "object_name": "table",
        "business_key_column": "table_bk",
        "except_column_list": "change_date",
        "sequence_column": "change_date"
    },
    "object2"...
}
```

[image]

Later, the target notebook should obtain the parameters in the pipeline configuration and load the tables accordingly. Can I obtain the pipeline configuration setting in the target notebook? If yes: How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can get the pipeline configuration setting in the notebook using spark configuration.

As mentioned in [this](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/properties.html#config-settings) documentation
the configuration setting are available in pipeline queries through spark configuration.

[image]

You can access using below statement
`spark.conf.get("key")`.

Below is the configuration given.
[image]

And accessed in notebook.

```
import dlt

@dlt.table(
comment="The raw wikipedia clickstream dataset, ingested from /databricks-datasets."
)
def clickstream_raw():
    json_path = spark.conf.get("json_path")
    return (spark.read.format("json").load(json_path))
```

[image]

Based on given path the dataframe is returned.

In your case you can get it like below.

```
import dlt

@dlt.table()
def object_list():
    import json
    
    json_obj = json.loads(spark.conf.get("object_list"))
    data = [json.dumps(json_obj[i]) for i in json_obj]
    json_df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data))
    return json_df
```

After getting json object you can use it accordingly.

Output:
[image]

and

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that answer! I was also able to acheive the same behavior using dbutils.widets.get:
json.loads(dbutils.widgets.get("json_path"))